# How to scan both current and some other package with @ComponentScan?

Tags: java, spring, component-scan

If I write only

```
@ComponentScan
```

Spring will scan the current package and below.

If I write

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"my.package.com"})
```

Can I specify current package implicitly along with some explicit packages?

Something like this

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"", "my.package.com"})
```

Comment: You can add multiple `@ComponentScan` annotations on the class.

Comment: Or you can just specify your package instead of "".

Answer (score 2):

The [JavaDoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html) says:

> If specific packages are not defined, scanning will occur from the
>   package of the class that declares this annotation.

So if you declare any package to be scan the default behavior will be overridden.
However I cannot see the reason why you need to have implicit scan for current package as long as it is not something that will be changed in runtime.
If you want to protected yourself in case of refactoring, you can use Type-safe [basePackageClasses](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html#basePackageClasses--) instead:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = {Config.class, ClassInPackageToScan.class})
```